# How to change order of bar chart categories?

Tags: pgfplots

I have a bar chart where the categories (on the x-axis) are numbers:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.csv}
x,y
1,4
2,7
3,2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, xtick={1,2,3}]
\addplot[x=x, y=y, fill] table[col sep=comma] {foo.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the columns to be plotted in the order [2,3,1] rather than [1,2,3]. Unfortunately, if I just use `xtick={2,3,1}` instead of `xtick={1,2,3}`, nothing changes. Presumably, pgfplots thinks that 1, 2, and 3 are *numbers*, but I want them to be understood as *categories* in my context. How can I reorder my columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `symbolic x coords`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.csv}
x,y
1,4
2,7
3,2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, symbolic x coords={2,3,1},xtick=data]
\addplot[x=x, y=y, fill] table[col sep=comma] {foo.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```